# Is it possible to stop/start an Azure ARM Virtual Machine from an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Runbooks can be used to stop/start classic and ARM Virtual Machines in Azure.

Is this also possible from an Azure Function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some good news to update this thread.  You will be able to do that now in Azure Functions.  The steps are documented here based on HTTP-triggered Functions.

[Azure Function role like permissions to Stop Azure Virtual Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838619/azure-function-role-like-permissions-to-stop-azure-virtual-machines/40883318#40883318)

You may switch out the trigger type to fit your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

See Ling's response above. We've addressed this now. :)

<strike>It's not currently possible to do this via the Azure PowerShell commandlets in Azure Functions. You can write against the Azure C# SDK or use the x-plat CLI (if you bring it yourself, as it isn't installed by default). You'll need to upload a cert or use a service account to perform those actions.</strike>

FYI - I'm on the Functions team and we're working on improving this story, in the near future. I'll update this answer once it's been made possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `Azure REST API` from here -> [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/start) or make use of the [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.virtualmachinesoperationsextensions.begincapture?view=azure-dotnet) to do the operations.